# Content elements for wordpress

Tags: wordpress, configuration, content-management-system, include

I'm looking for a plugin (or better yet, not a plugin) for wordpress that lets me generate standard content elements, or includes for posts and pages.

For example, my_content_1 could be:

**buy it now for $23!!**

Which could then be included in posts and pages using some kind of syntax (or whatever) like:

Welcome to my site, blah blah blah.. check out this product - %my_content_1%

Not looking for anything fancy, anything that does this sort of thing would be awesome.

The point of this being much like a regular php include I could have the same information updated in one place and applied over many pages/posts.

I found something that is pretty much what I'm looking for:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/reusables/

However, other suggestions would be good as I'm not too confident in the quality of the code for that plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found something that is pretty much what I'm looking for:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/reusables/

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about a plugin, but how about simply creating something yourself? If you created a PHP page and set up variables such as

```
$content->title = "This is a title"
$content->smallText = "Insert some short paragraph here"
```

And then just include it in your header? You could store it in your theme directory and then call it like so

```
<?php $themeFolder = get_bloginfo("template_url"); ?>
<?php include($themeFolder."/content.php") ?>
```

Would that be suitable?

Comment: I was looking for something a bit more user friendly - might just create something myself! Good answer though, modded up.

Comment: Fair enough, noticed you found a plugin - properly the best way to go.

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a few files and link them in using shortcode?
ie: open your themes/functions.php file add this..

```
<?php
function wp_my_shortcodes($atts) 
{
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
                            'type' => '',  //author, rss, adverts
                            ), $atts));
    switch($type) {
        case 'author'   : $display = wp_display_author_info(); break;
        case 'rssview'  : $display = wp_display_rss_info(); break;
        case 'adverts'  : $display = wp_display_adverts(); break;
        default     : $display = wp_display_author_info(); break;
    }
    return $display ;                       
}
add_shortcode('mycontent', wp_my_shortcodes);


function wp_display_author_info()
{
    include(TEMPLATEPATH.'/my_author_info.php');    
}
function wp_display_rss_info()
{
    include(TEMPLATEPATH.'/my_rss_info.php');   
}
function wp_display_adverts()
{
    include(TEMPLATEPATH.'/my_adverts.php');    
}
?>
```

using shortcodes inside your posts you can then bring in which ever piece of content that you want.. in the example above I've created 3 pages in the template root folder called
my_author_info.php, my_rss_info.php, my_adverts.php all of which speak for themself..

**my_author_info.php**
this page could use the [the_author_meta()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_author_meta) to populate a div box with included author info,

**my_rss_info.php**
include your subscription box to let users subscribe to your blog

**my_adverts.php**
include 4x 125x125 adverts?

so in the post i could use

```
[mycontent type='author']
[mycontent type='rssview']
[mycontent type='adverts']
```

if no argument is added to the shortcode then the default view is shown, in this case..

```
[mycontent]
```

would return the authorview as default...
this would then include that file in the content...

just remember to create the included files :)